# Are there any connections between the Humans of Earth being called Tau'ri by the Goa'uld and the tribe called the Tauri from Crimea in any literature?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, history

The Goa'uld, having been separated from the Humans of Earth ([Tau'ri](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Tau%27ri)) around 3000 BCE, named them the Tau'ri to mean "First Ones". In our history, the two histories being virtually identical aside from finding a stargate in Giza, there was a tribe, probably Greek in origin, called the [Tauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauri) that lived in the Crimean peninsula at some point between 1000 - 1 BCE.

***Has anyone seen any reference to this duality in any canon or non-canon literature?*** Edit 6/16/21: In or out of universe. I was expecting any answer to this to be writers commentary or something similar, honestly.

Comment: Did...I do something wrong? lmfao

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why there are downvotes here to be honest. Could someone care to explain?

Comment: Seems like a fair question. If yes, I think it would have to be out of universe.

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me (hence my downvote). As Pratchett pointed out,  there's only so many syllables to go around. Perhaps we might ask if the Scottish landowners known as "Tories" were in some way related.

Comment: So, a question asking if anyone has seen a connection deserves a downvote because a connection is unlikely? Seems legit. lol @Valorum

Comment: @DuirUnknown - You did ask. That someone used a similar (note, not identical) sounding word *thousands of years later* seems a tenuous link, at best.

Comment: Tau is a Greek letter pronounced exactly as it is in Tau'ri. Ri is an almost universal syllable, with almost every language pronouncing it as "ree". To elaborate further, the "ri" in Tauri likely came from the Scythian alphabet as the original way of discerning that these peoples were a mixture of Greek(Tau) and Scythian(Ri), later becoming the Scythotauri, amongst other names, likely when the Greeks got too comfortable considering the Tauri as predominately Greek.  @Valorum

Comment: Do you mean in-universe or out? A lot of the names in Stargate are taken from places in Europe. For example, Abydos is both the desert planet from the film and a city in Egypt.

Comment: @samuei Egypt is not in Europe. :D

Comment: @DuirUnknown I feel you should submit your comment as answer, while there is probably no definitive answer, it is clearly well researched and a sound and compelling hypothesis